Why bot.reaction() by Telegraf.js for Telegram Bot doesn't work?
Trying to develop a telegram bot with Telegraf.js when I try to listen message reactions the code doesn't work.
The code appears the same as Telegraf 4.16.0 Release Notes - Working with Reactions
My demo code:
const {Telegraf} = require('telegraf');

const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// Load DOTENV
dotenv.config();
// Config
const BOT_TOKEN = process.env.BOT_TOKEN || '';
// Init bot
const bot = new Telegraf(BOT_TOKEN);

bot.reaction("", (ctx) => {
    // user added a  reaction
    console.log("added")
});

bot.launch();
console.log(`Launch local with token: ${BOT_TOKEN}`)

package.json - dependencies
"dependencies": {
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "mongodb": "^4.13.0",
    "rss-parser": "^3.12.0",
    "telegraf": "^4.16.3"
  }

I have tried with specific version 4.16.0 and other ways like bot.on('message_reaction') but anything happened
Thanks for the help.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Was having same problem here, turns out that reactions are not send by Telegram by default, you have to enable it.
// enable updates from reactions
bot.launch({ allowedUpdates: [ "message", "message_reaction" ] });

